# How use two Decklink cards with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a computer with two DeckLink Quad cards each with 4 inputs and 4 outputs.

If I list the ffmpeg sources shows duplicate names for decklink devices:

```
Auto-detected sources for decklink:
  48:00000000:00300600 [DeckLink SDI (1)]
  48:00000000:00300500 [DeckLink SDI (2)]
  48:00000000:00300400 [DeckLink SDI (3)]
  48:00000000:00300300 [DeckLink SDI (4)]
  48:00000000:00300d00 [DeckLink SDI (1)]
  48:00000000:00300c00 [DeckLink SDI (2)]
  48:00000000:00300b00 [DeckLink SDI (3)]
  48:00000000:00300a00 [DeckLink SDI (4)]
```

Also with "ffmpeg -f decklink -list_devices 1 -i dummy" command:

```
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80] Blackmagic DeckLink input devices:
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (1)'
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (2)'
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (3)'
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (4)'
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (1)'
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (2)'
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (3)'
[decklink @ 0x55d13de4fe80]     'DeckLink SDI (4)'
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

How I have to use the device name as input I can only use one of the two cards.
Does anyone know if there is any option to use the device by its id or similar instead a device name?

The BlackmagicFirmwareUpdater status return:

```
0:      /dev/blackmagic/dv3 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
1:      /dev/blackmagic/dv2 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
2:      /dev/blackmagic/dv1 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
3:      /dev/blackmagic/dv0 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
4:      /dev/blackmagic/dv7 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
5:      /dev/blackmagic/dv6 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
6:      /dev/blackmagic/dv5 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
7:      /dev/blackmagic/dv4 [DeckLink SDI]      0x36    OK
```

Thanks.

Comment: I answer myself. I have tried using the DeviceHandle  "48:00000000:00300d00"  instead of   "DeckLink SDI (1)"  and it works correctly. This way there are no problems with duplicate names.

Comment: This is a great solution. Please consider converting your comment into an official answer (it's perfectly fine to answer your own question).